# Default Browser Checkboxes Showing Up in Addition to Angular-Material md-checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, checkbox, angular-material

[image]I am using Angular material elements in my Angular 2 app, and in one section where I'm using md-checkboxes I'm noticing that with Chrome, both the UI for the md-checkboxes as *well as* what looks like the default browser checkboxes are showing up. How do I disable the default browser UI checkboxes from showing up?

```
<md-checkbox class="request-option" [checked]="hasBeenRequested()"
             (change)="onOptionSelected($event, 'ct')">Consulting
</md-checkbox>
```

Here are the styles being applied according to the browser:

```
element.style {
}
default-theme.css:205
.chart-content .scroll-panel * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
<style>…</style>
.mat-checkbox-input {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
}
<style>…</style>
.cdk-visually-hidden {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-transform: none;
    width: 1px;
}
default-theme.css:195
.chart-content * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
default-theme.css:413
input {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 8px;
    outline: none;
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="checkbox" i] {
    -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="radio" i], input[type="checkbox" i] {
    background-color: initial;
    cursor: default;
    margin: 3px 0.5ex;
    padding: initial;
    border: initial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    cursor: text;
    padding: 1px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, select, button {
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: initial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    margin: 0em;
    font: 400 11px system-ui;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, select, button, meter, progress {
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
```

And my "computed" tab shows this:

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-top-style: none;
border-top-width: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
clip: rect(0px 0px 0px 0px);
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
cursor: default;
display: block;
inline-blockinput, textarea, select, buttonuser agent stylesheet
font-family: system-ui;
font-size: 14px;
font-stretch: 100%;
font-style: normal;
font-variant-caps: normal;
font-variant-east-asian: normal;
font-variant-ligatures: normal;
font-variant-numeric: normal;
font-weight: 400;
height: 1px;
left: 10px;
letter-spacing: normal;
line-height: normal;
margin-bottom: -1px;
margin-left: -1px;
margin-right: -1px;
margin-top: -1px;
outline-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
position: absolute;
text-align: start;
text-indent: 0px;
text-rendering: auto;
text-shadow: none;
text-transform: none;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 1px;
word-spacing: 0px;
writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
-webkit-appearance: checkbox;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
-webkit-border-image: none;
```

Comment: When you inspect the HTML in the F12 window, do you see any style attribute applied to the input element, which would make it visible? For example, a global `display` attribute set in another CSS file.

Comment: Looked into this, and I don't see any global styles being applied here that I can see that would cause this.

Comment: [Here](https://embed.plnkr.co/eB9aspHphD0lISJDUla9/) is a working plunker.  I was unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Can you post a screen capture of the styles  applied to the input element? From what I see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-md-checkbox-change-event-example), the `cdk-visually-hidden` class should make it invisible.

Comment: Added applied styles in my question above, and cdk-visually-hidden is being applied.

Comment: In the "Computed" tab, do you see a size of 1 x 1, and a margin of -1 x -1? Is there a border?

Comment: Added what shows for my "computed" tab above.

Comment: Are you sure that these are the computed values for the input element? They look like those of its parent div with `mat-checkbox-inner-container`.

Comment: Think you're right. Edited the computed tab output above.

Comment: I don't know how that element can be visible. You really see it? It has a size of 1 x 1, and no border. Maybe you see another input element.

Comment: Nope. That's the one. I can see it, and the same goes for the other checkboxes in that section. Each one shows a duplicate -- one with the md-checkbox styling, and then the default browser styling shows as well.

Comment: I wonder if I can do a /deep/ override with display:none applied to an element?

Comment: What size do you see in the "Computed" image, above the attributes list? You could add `visibility: hidden` to the `.cdk-visually-hidden` class style, in a global CSS file. Setting `display: none` may cause trouble when setting/getting the check state.

Comment: Will look into that. By the way, above I added a screenshot of what I see.

Comment: Can you add a capture of the "Computed" tab top image?

Comment: A size of 346 x 24 does not match the details given for the input element.

Comment: Aha! Your suggestion worked. Adding the .cdk-visually-hidden class to my root style sheet, with visibility:hidden, worked. Many thanks! If you want to add that as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `cdk-visually-hidden` is assigned to the HTML input element inside the Angular Material checkbox, and should make it invisible. If you don't find another way to prevent the element from being displayed, you can add the following style to a global CSS file of your application:

```
.cdk-visually-hidden
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It's better to use `display: none` instead of `visibility: hidden` as the later will hide the component while still preserve the space taken.

Comment: Actually both display:none and visibility:hidden might be hidden from screen readers. Consider the following: 
[cdk-visually-hidden] {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: -500px;
}